# How to inherit from a custom node of a gdnative plugin, in gdnative?

Tags: c++, godot, inheritance

### Context

I am developing a game in gdnative and I would like to design it in several "modules", where there would be:

- a main module for the core gameplay,
- a second module that I defined as a plugin

### Approach

In my plugin there is a custom node, which needs to have a `_process` method, defined according to the need, to be used in my core gameplay module, and in the game.

But if I understand correctly Godot doesn't allow this, because it is designed to be data and component oriented, i.e. I can't create subnodes from a custom node.
Also, since both modules are in gdnative, I'm not sure if the custom type I'm going to use for inheritance is recognized at compile time.

I should rather allow to add to my custom node, a "Behavior" component that would be created in the core gameplay module, to customize its `_process` method.

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some level we could argue for Godot being data oriented (e.g. the code inside the "servers", such as `VisualServer` and so on), or we can argue that the scene tree is composition (well, aggregation), and thus the children `Node`s could be considered components. However, in general Godot is object oriented.

Scripts - and including GDNative scripts - extend classes, such as `Node` and derived classes. For that, those classes must be exposed for scripting. Which means they are registered in `ClassDB`.

In is in that last point that you will run into issues. You need to make sure the classes are registered in `ClassDB` so scripts - including GDNative scripts - can use them.

It is one of the limitations of the GDNative system that its classes do not get registered into `ClassDB`, which means other scripts cannot extend them.  As a result there are things that cannot be done with GDNative, and must be done as [modules](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/custom_modules_in_cpp.html). *This limitation does not stem from a philosophy against object oriented programming. In fact, [GDExtension](https://godotengine.org/article/introducing-gd-extensions) - the replacement for GDNative in Godot 4.0 - addresses this limitation.*

**Note**: When I say "module" I mean modules added to Godot source code, for which you need to build Godot with them. So, when I say "module" I don't mean GDNative. See [Custom modules in C++](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/custom_modules_in_cpp.html).

Thus, to answer the question on the title: You can't inherit from a custom node of a GDNative plugin, because they do not get registered into `ClassDB`. If you want to define classes that can be inherited in C++, you should create a module (and I reiterate that by "module" I mean [module](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/custom_modules_in_cpp.html), and that they require to build Godot form source), or wait for Godot 4.0.

That does not mean different GDNative scripts cannot talk to each other. However, if you are going to use C++, but you are not going to build Godot form source, nor wait for Godot 4.0… You would want to workaround inheritance.

Consider using the scene tree. You could either:

- Have the GDNative node call a method on its children.
- Or, have another node intended to have the GDNative as child, and call methods on it.